# PVC leak under slab in outdoor waterfall feature

Tags: plumbing, repair, pvc, underground

I've searched the internet for a solution to my problem and I can't find anything that even references a potential fix.  Maybe one doesn't even exist, but I have to try, right?  So, here is my problem.  I have an outdoor man-made waterfall.  Of course, to get the waterfall to work, you need a sump pump and a pipe going back to the top to continue with the waterfall.  One winter I must not have winterized the return pipe well enough and a crack happened that now drains the water from the system in a matter of days. I need a fix that doesn't involve tearing up the ground to replace the portion of the damaged pipe.  Something akin to how you might fix a leaking radiator with pepper or egg yolks.  If anyone here knows of a product or home remedy that would work on this problem I would be grateful.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get to both ends of that pipe, then I would slide a flexible pipe inside the broken one and connect to that...

Comment: An interesting thought.  I will look into that.  Although the run of the pipe has a significant length of about 20 feet.  How would I pull the sleeve through the pipe?

Comment: Use a pull cord or rope.

Comment: A pull cord or rope would not have the stiffness needed to make it through without bunching up somewhere inside the pipe.  The diameter of the pipe is about an inch and a half.  Please don't take my reply comments as a dissuasion on your ideas.  I'm appreciative.

Comment: So use a ball pulling a thin thread and push it through with the water, then pull a thicker string through etc

Comment: I could see that working as long as I can seal the string on the pump end from leaking out too much to maintain enough water pressure and push the ball of string through to the other end.  Good idea.

Comment: I believe that on some runs of electrical conduit a shop vac is sometimes used to pull a light ball of fluff with cord attached. Then the cord is used to pull a rope heavy enough to pull what needs to be pulled. But you could use an electrical fishing tape.  But if there are 90 degree bends in the PVC piping putting PEX piping through would not work.  It is an advantage that the diameter is 1.5 inch.